# "ssh-keygen" no se se reconoce como un comando interno o externo en Windows 7

Tags: ssh

al intentar ejecutar el comando "ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096" en la carpeta de mi proyecto de laravel, me aparece este mensaje de error:

"ssh-keygen" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: falta información si lo estas corriendo en local o en producción y sobre que SO estas usando?

Comment: es local y estoy usando windows 7

Comment: Es necesario que pongas dentro de tu pregunta qué SO utilizas o con que consola o entorno trabajas (ej.: WSL, Git Bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

en windows 7:

Para generar una clave con PuTTY, deberías:

Descargar y ejecutar el generador puttygen.exe.

En la sección "Parameters" elegir SSH2 DSA y presionar Generate.

Mueve tu ratón aleatoriamente en la pantalla pequeña para generar un par de claves.

Introduce un comentario clave, que la identificará (es útil cuando usas varias claves SSH).

Escribe en el passphrase y confírmalo. El passphrase se usa para proteger
tu clave.

Se te pedirá cuando te conectes por SSH.

Haz clic en "Save private key" para guardar tu clave privada.

Haz clic en "Save public key" para guardar tu clave pública.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: editado. había dejado ambas opciones porque la cabecera de la pregunta no indica SO y a alguien mas cuando busque le podría servir.

Comment: En la seccion de parameters me sale: RSA, DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519, SSH-1(RSA), acaso la SSH2 DSA viene en otra version?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que intentas generar una clave SSH para un proyecto de laravel en Windows 7.

En  **Windows** puedes usar cualquier tipo de cliente SSH, te recomiendo [PuTTY](https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/getting-started/ssh-keys/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-windows) para generar la Clave SSH ya que tiene interfaz gráfica.

Comment: peeeero si tiene instalado localmente openssl o similar, no necesita putty. Con abrir la consola y correr el binario (o poner la ruta en la variable de entorno path), va a poder hacer esto sin putty

Comment: @Alfabravo tienes razón, el puede usar cualquier tipo de cliente para generar la clave  SSH.Sin embargo creo que OpenSSL no viene preinstalado en Windows 7 así que también deberá instalarlo, ya queda a elección de el cual programa utilizar.

Comment: De acuerdo. Es cuestión de explicar por qué putty o por qué no putty. Por ejemplo, si instala Git en Windows, el git bash trae openssl. :)

Answer (score 0):

Descargue el git bash y lo ejecute en la carpeta del proyecto luego ejecute los comandos necesarios en este caso el ssh-keygen y funciono